# ksh: shell eval function output same count after insert

Tags: shell, unix, eval, ksh

I'm trying to put my `ksh` script code into variable to execute later it with eval

Example dummy script logic

===========================

> my_command=$(cat << EOF
>
> ```
> ###//function count  records in database table
>
> record_before=$(count_records $table_name)
>
> ###//function inserting record to database table
>
> insert_records $table_name
>
> ###//function count  records in database table after insert
>
> record_after=$(count_records $table_name)
> ```
>
> EOF)

============

```
eval "$my_command"
```

Problem is that if I still inserting one record record_before and record_after still contain same amount of records. 
Example:
Table have 1 records.
record_before =1
Inserting new record table now have 2 records
record_after=1

record_after should have 2 records instead of 1

Any advices?

*** SOLVED ***
You should put single quotes around executed function to work properly in EVAL

record_before='$(count_records $table_name)'

record_after='$(count_records $table_name)'

Found something new, to avoid QUOTING around code I'm now using

var=$(CAT<<'EOF'
...
EOF)

Comment: Huh, I think I just found where problem was: record_before='$(count_records $table_name)' , I should put single quotes around calling functions

Comment: You really don't want to be using `cat` in this way.  The variable expansion is happening before the `eval` unless you include single quotes.

Comment: Don't forget to quote `$table_name` in the `insert_records` line as well.  Otherwise, changing `table_name` in your environment and then `eval`ing will not work properly.  You really should use a shell function for this.

Comment: Ok, so seems problem is in used cat function - it extracting variables before they got executed in eval, can you maybe advice how to put code to varible using my_var=<<EOF A LOT OF CODE WITH QUOTES   EOF without cat?

Comment: Why aren't you using a shell function instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign the script to a variable directly.  The shell language allows for multi-line strings without any special syntax.

```
my_command='count_records $table_name
insert_records $table_name
count_records $table_name'
```

If you echo `"$my_command"`, you get exactly what you would expect.  Using the string with `eval` will work as well.  With that said, I would write this using a shell function instead of eval'ing a string.

```
update_table() {
    table_name=$1
    count_records $table_name
    insert_records $table_name
    count_records $table_name
}

# "call" the function just like it was any other command
update_table tablename
```

Depending on why you are doing this, you can insert the function in a shell library somewhere and `source` it into a script or add the function in your `$HOME/.profile` (or `$HOME/.kshrc`) and `update_table` will be available in your shell environment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Probably it will work also, but in my case in stored to variable code I have a lot different quotes like: ' , " , ` . Then just single quotes around my code will not work

Comment: Don't store the _code_ in a variable then.  That is why shell functions were invented.  They let you simply write shell code without worrying about escaping quotes.